# Kentico 8 SMTP Server Settings

Tags: email, kentico

Currently i have an installation on Kentico 8.

I'm trying to configure the SMTP server and i can't seem to find any settings to implicitly set a PORT and Encryption type.

is this possible?

When hovering over the helper tooltip it keeps telling me that i can add more on the Advanced SMTP Server Settings. But where is the

so the question is

- Can i implicitly set the PORT and Encryption type?
- Where is the Advanced SMTP Server Settings Located?

Answer (score 3):

Port should be entered as a part of the SMTP server name (or IP). I doubt that you can set encryption type somewhere.

Advanced SMTP settings can be found in applications:

[image: SMTP servers Kentico application]

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Configuring+SMTP+servers).

Comment: thats odd, i get a No matching applications found.when searching for the SMTP word and on my configuration there is no smtp server.

Comment: @tomexsans Multiple/Advanced SMTP is only available with EMS license.